# Adding delimiter to a string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, cut

I am extracting ascii data from network packages captured by `tcpdump`. I have manipulated the data to the point I am on a single string and now need to cut it. The problem the left over string has the package header followed by the ascii data.

A string example is

```
+%_!^0r,zK"5÷fgf/Nametoextractanothernametoextracthostname1.1.1.12.1iwm876
```

Now the names to extract can change and be different. The hostname is the the variable I am using a constant. I want to add a delimiter in front of the host name so I can then use cut to remove the junk at the end of the string.

An example would be of the desired result

```
+%_!^0r,zK"5÷fgf/Nametoextractanothernametoextract:hostname1.1.1.12.1iwm876
```

So I can then use cut to get this output:

```
Nametoextract anothernametoextract
```

Comment: Given `Nametoextract` can be different, how do you expect to delimit it? Or is that not part of the question?

Comment: Right now the name to extract is being printed in the same line as the othername. For this question i am wondering how to get the : in front of the host name.

Comment: `awk -F'[/|.]' '{gsub(/hostname[[:digit:]]/,""); print $2}'`

Comment: Yup that worked for one of the packet capture files. It left a 0 at the end of the trailing. On the other (similar format the hostname changed only) i am getting numeric output of 66 only. I gave the code a go on another project and it filled a gap i had. Thanks so much.

Comment: I missed an `*` after `[[:digit:]]` to match more than one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailing part seems to be easy, just remove from the 'hostname' (and a number) on :

```
$ a='+%_!^0r,zK"5÷fgf/Nametoextractanothernametoextracthostname1.1.1.12.1iwm876'

$ echo ${a%hostname[0-9]*}

+%_!^0r,zK"5÷fgf/Nametoextractanothernametoextract
```

Comment: Yep this did the trick. Works with both of my packet capture files. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @ltstrom Maybe you should read this: [What should I do when I get a correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)